# Use dotted YAML variables file in Ansible

Tags: variables, ansible, format, yaml

I'm trying to achieve the following using Ansible:

Define a YAML file with some variables **in the dotted format** inside it (variables.yml)

```
database.hosts[0]: "db0"
database.hosts[1]: "db1"
database.hosts[2]: "db2"

foo.bar: 1
foo.baz: 2
```

Load the variables in variables.yml by using the **include_vars** module in my playbook (playbook.yml) and print them in a tree structure

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: not
  tasks:
    - name: "Loading vars"
      run_once: true
      include_vars:
        file: 'variables.yml'

    - name: "Testing"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ foo }}"

    - name: "Testing"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ database }}"
```

Running this results in the following error:

```
fatal: [host0]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'foo' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '.../playbook.yml': line 9, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: \"Testing\"\n      ^ here\n"}
```

Which makes it clear that each property in the YAML file has been loaded as a separate property and not as properties within two trees rooted in **database** and **foo**.

Of course, the playbook works as expected if I specify the properties as follows:

```
database:
  hosts:
    - "db0"
    - "db1"
    - "db2"        

foo:
  bar: 1
  baz: 2
```

However, I need the YAML variables file to be in the dotted format instead of in the classic indented format. Is there any way to achieve this? E.g.: a module different from include_vars or some configuration that I can add to the ansible.cfg file? I have already tried to use **hash_behaviour=merge**, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: ***"I need the YAML variables file to be in the dotted format instead of in the classic indented format. Is there any way to achieve this?"***

A: No. It's' not possible. See [Creating valid variable names](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names).